# Is there a way to be the C-4 carrier every round in CSS?

Tags: counter-strike-source

When I play with bots as a terrorist, I want to be the C-4 carrier in every round. Is there a cheat or a command to make that happen?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Entering `bot_defer_to_human "1"` in the console makes it so bots won't be able to use "human" items, including the C4. If you're the only human player on your team, this will cause you to always spawn with the bomb.

Comment: Great. Now finally, i dont have to wait for them stupid bots :)

Answer (score 2):

While creating the server, go to CPU player options and then click *"Bots defer goals to humans"*.

After this start the server and enjoy - you will always have the bomb from now

Comment: Good to know that it is an option outside the console